# Wantarray equivalent?

Tags: perl, powershell

in Perl (how I miss it), I could detect the calling context of a function, specifically to tell whether the function's return value was being discarded (void context) or assigned to a scalar or list variable.

this allowed some very elegant expressions.  Is there an equivalent in Powershell (I haven't managed to find one)?

Comment: As I understand it, Perl's concept of context is unique amongst programming languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use $host.runspace.runningpipelines (or $host.runspace.GetCurrentlyRunningPipeline()) to access the "local pipeline". The local pipeline has a "commands" member. Each entry in this array, of type Management.Automation.Runspaces.Command, represents a command/script that is part of a running pipeline. Runspaces.Command has a member CommandText which has the full text of the running pipeline (whereas $myinvocation only has the current line). You could parse CommandText for things like out-null, [void] cast, and assignment to $null. Note that the powershell parser is documented in some blogs and could be used to aid parsing.

Both runningpipelines and GetCurrentlyRunningPipeline() are private members of RunSpace, so you'd need to access them via reflection.

Comment: wow.  it's complicated (and perhaps more trouble than it's worth) but I'm going to call this an answer (with a point).  thanks for thinking this through

Comment: I agree it may be more trouble than its worth. Even if you implemented this technique, in some cases you couldn't be sure of the context, because the variable to be assigned might not exist when the function using wantarray is invoked. And powershell doesn't have a syntactical indication of whether a variable is an array or not, so parsing the statement doesn't help. But you could take a different tact and say that if the function is part of a pipeline then it is an "array context", but if part of an assignment statement it is a scalar context. In effect: Powershellize the wantarray concept!

Answer (score 0):

In general, PowerShell favors explicit preferences over implicit, context-dependent behavior. For example:

- Verbose output is hidden by default, but can be configured with the [`-Verbose`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113216) parameter or the [`$VerbosePreference`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113248) variable.
- Unconsumed output is displayed by the host with default type-based formatting, but can be configured to display particular members with explicit `Format-___` calls.
- Files updated by [`Rename-Item`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113382) are not returned by default, but you can use the `-PassThru` parameter to have them output to the pipeline.
- Saving the output of a command into a variable (e.g. `$x = Get-ChildItem`) will default to null if no items are returned, the item if only one is returned, or an array if multiple items are returned; but this can be overridden by explicitly asking for an array with `$x = @(Get-ChildItem)`.

You could argue that `$renamedItems = Rename-Item ...` or `Rename-Item ... | Out-Default` might be more convenient at times compared to `$renamedItems = Rename-Item ... -PassThru`. However, it is much harder to explain why items magically appear in `$renamedItems` in the first call, when `Rename-Item` on its own produces nothing. (Or worse, if `$variable = Some-Command` happened to change its output between one item or multiple items based on whether the last value assigned to `$variable` happened to be a scalar or an enumerable value.)

---

Having said that, you can gather a lot of information from the [`$MyInvocation`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113212) automatic variable. For example, you can examine the [`PipelinePosition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.invocationinfo.pipelineposition.aspx) and [`PipelineLength`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.invocationinfo.pipelinelength.aspx) properties to determine whether the call is a part of a larger pipeline, or use the [`Line`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.invocationinfo.line.aspx) and [`OffsetInLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.invocationinfo.offsetinline.aspx) properties (perhaps with some [parsing logic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.psparser.aspx)) to determine whether there is an assignment or cast of the call's output.

Whether users will find the results consistent and predictable is another matter :)

Comment: Emperor XLII, it's precisely the behaviour of $x = Get-Children that I'm looking for i.e. I'd like to be able to write functions that behave the same way

Comment: @ekkis: The null/single/array behavior is an aspect of PowerShell; all cmdlets behave this way, not just `Get-ChildItem`. For example, this function has the same behavior with no special code: `function f( $count ) { for( $i = 0; $i -lt $count; ++$i ) { $i } }` (i.e. `$x = f 0` → null, `$x = f 1` → single value, `$x = f 2` → array).